# 'uiprintf' error in android PAC ROM compilation

Tags: android

I am getting this error while compiling PAC ROM.. I found printf error was discussed before and adviced to include  . but this doesn't seems to work for uiPrintf.
This the exact line: 
device/cyanogen/msm8916-common/recovery/recovery_updated.c:171.9: error: implicit declaration of function 'uiprintf'

Pls help..

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit declaration** means using a function without declaring it before. Generally it used to give a warning for other cm based rom but pac makes this strict.

For your info,
`uiprintf` function's definition is in path  `"bootable/recovery/updater/install.h"`, and the datatypes used in the function are in `updater.h`. You may manually add the definitions but it will give an error after long time(almost at end) about redeclaration of `uiprintf` function.

To get along with this error just comment out that line in `recovery-updater.c`. It will not hurt anything (It's just for recovery ui printing).